# Range validation is not working fine in yii

Tags: php, validation, yii

I Have three separate text boxes  for DAY, MONTH, YEAR .When I submitting the form it should validate the rules using range validator. Here I wrote the code in my model.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
       array('yyyy,mm,dd', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
         array('yyyy', 'in','range'=>array(1950,2000));
         array('mm', 'in','range'=>array(0,11));
         array('dd', 'in','range'=>array(0,30));
       );
}
```

Its not validating , Help me with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by `compare`, like

```
array('latitude', 'compare','operator'=>'<=','compareValue'=>90, 'message'=>'maximum is 90 which is North Pole'  ),
array('latitude', 'compare','operator'=>'>=','compareValue'=>0  ),
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25286-yii-numbers-range-validator/

because `range` you have to give all possible true values in that array

Comment: ` array('dd', 'compare','operator'=>'<=','compareValue'=>31, 'message'=>'Not a Valid Day', 'on'=>'register' ),
            array('dd', 'compare','operator'=>'>=','compareValue'=>0,'on'=>'register'  ), `




This also not working

Comment: **yyyy,mm,dd** - are these the proper model attributes? Could you post the AR model code?